Python `speech_recognition` Script Stuck on `recognizer.listen()` Without `phrase_time_limit`
I'm working with the speech_recognition library in Python, and my script is getting stuck on the recognizer.listen() call. I want to continuously listen for commands after detecting the wake word but am encountering issues. Here’s a snippet of my code:
import speech_recognition as sr

recognizer = sr.Recognizer()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Initialize Jarvis......")

    while True:
        try:
            with sr.Microphone() as source:
                print("\nListening...")
                audio = recognizer.listen(source, timeout=2, phrase_time_limit=2)

            Word = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)

            if Word.lower() == "jarvis":
                print("Wake word detected!")

                with sr.Microphone() as source:
                    print("\nListening...")
                    audio = recognizer.listen(source)
                    command = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
                    print(command)

        except Exception as x:
            print(f"Error : {x}")

Issue:
When running the script, it successfully detects the wake word but then gets stuck on the second recognizer.listen() call. I would like to continuously listen for commands without using the phrase_time_limit parameter.
Error 
Environment:

OS: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

How can I fix this issue?
When running the script, it successfully detects the wake word but then gets stuck on the second recognizer.listen() call. I would like to continuously listen for commands without using the phrase_time_limit parameter.
Error
